# A way to insert a value in an empty List in a specific index

Tags: python, list, insert, append, extend

Is there a way to insert a specific value into a List into a specific index. List should be completely empty:

```
L = []
L.insert(2,177)
print(L)
```

L should give out the values of L [ , ,117].

Comment: Lists can't have holes. You have to put *something* into the first two slots.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Maybe a dictionary with the desired position as the index is more appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Maybe : `L.append((2,177))` :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not possible. Lists cannot have "holes"; every slot in the list must contain a value.

You have two options:

1. Fill the list with dummy values:

   ```
   L = [None] * 3
   L[2] = 177
   # L: [None, None, 177]
   ```
2. Use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) rather than a list:

   ```
   L = {}
   L[2] = 177
   # L: {2: 177}
   ```

   A dict is a mapping between arbitrary values, so it can handle "holes" with no problem.

Comment: This provides a solution fitting the OPs requirement using a list, but also provides a better solution using a dictionary instead. +1.

Answer (score 3):

iterables in Python must have objects inside. You can fill the list with `None` up to the place you want your actual value

```
l = [None for _ in range(200)]
l[2] = 2
l[177] = 177
```

> None
>
> The sole value of `types.NoneType. None` is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a function.

Comment: My opinion: The Python user does not store values of `None`. @Mr. T comment are good.